# where are eclipse folders located after installation with the command apt-get in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: eclipse, lombok, ubuntu-20.04

I would like to configure Lombok after  installation of eclipse, but the problem is that,the paths i entered does not work for Lombok. I entered

`/home/username/snap/eclipse/`

and I received this message

```
I can't find any IDE that lombok supports at location /home/username/snap/eclipse/
```

Comment: This is almost more of a superuser or system administration question.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the path

```
/snap/eclipse/current/eclipse.ini
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).